# Image source resets after Navigating using App.current.MainPage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, navigation, master-detail

On Login, I am getting and storing some property(such as username, Date Created and Email) including the image path(of type string) property of the logged-in user in settings plugin and using it as the source of an image element in a Master Detail page. When i go to some other page and want to navigate back to the Master Detail Page using Application.Current.MainPage, every other property is retained but the image clears off which obviously means that the Image Path Property is lost. Does anyone have this problem and how was you able to solve it?

This is how I am storing Image Path property in JObject and in Settings:

```
 var imagepath = jObject.Value<string>("ImagePath");

   Settings.Path = imagepath;
```

This is how I am setting the path to the source of an image element:

```
     profileImg.Source = 
     string.Format(UrlConstants.url2,Settings.Path.Substring(1));
```

And this is how i am navigating from some other page to the Master Detail:

```
  Application.Current.MainPage = new PeppyMasterDetail();
```

This is my Constructor for the Master Page section of the Master Detail Page:

```
  public MasterPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            usernameLbl.Text = Settings.UserName;
            emailLbl.Text = Settings.Email;
            dateLbl.Text = "JOINED: " + Settings.Date;
            profileImg.Source = string.Format(UrlConstants.url2, Settings.Path.Substring(1));

        }
```

This is the constructor for my Master Detail Page

```
    public PeppyMasterDetail ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();                 
            mPage.listView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

        }
```

After Navigating using Application.Current.MainPage, I want to still be able to see my image without it being cleared off.

PS: This behavior does not occur when i navigate using Navigation.PushAsync or 
Navigation.PopAsync();

Comment: Why don't use Nagivation.PushAsync?

Comment: Because I do not want to have Navigation History of the page I'm navigatiing from . Meaning I don't want the use to be able to access the page I'm coming from when they press the back button in Android.

Comment: you are creating a new instance of PeppyMasterDetail(), so all of the values will be set to their defaults.  This is how c# is supposed to work.

Comment: Yeah I know. New is used to create a fresh instance of an object in c# but what baffles me is that it retains all other property except the image path which I'm using for the source of the image element. How would you explain that ?

Comment: without seeing the code I have no way of knowing what you're doing

Comment: I added it to my question. What other part would you want to see so I can update my question

Comment: the full constructor and OnAppearing

Comment: @Jason I did not override the OnAppearing method but i have edited my question and added the constructor of the master page section of the master detail and the constructor of the peppy master detail page.

Comment: I suggest you debug the line where you are setting profileImg.Source to see what the problem is.  Is Settings.Path not being saved correctly?  Or is your substring() failing?

Comment: Okay @Jason. I would look at that. But it does not lose its content when I'm navigating using pushasync and popasync. But it loses its content when I use application.current.mainpage.

Comment: When you push and pop typically the same instance of the page stays on the stack.  It does not create a new instance.

Comment: Okay I hope to get a solution to this issue when I debug while navigating back to that page using that navigation style. I will let you know if I see anything

Comment: @Jason i tried debugging that block of code and i figured it appends another set of string into the one there already and that is why it does not give any image since the image path is messed up. i know the problem now  but i cant wrap my head around a solution yet. If you have an idea on a solution, kindly fill me in

Comment: You should find out where you appends another set of string into the one there already. Search in your project everywhere you use Settings.Path and check the code.